# jquery change using timedropper plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin http://felicegattuso.com/projects/timedropper/ along with the datedropper, the datedropper on change function works fine, however the timedropper does not for some reason and I cant work out why. Here's my jquery code:

```
$('#departure, #alarm').change(function() {
var date = $('#departure').val();
var time = $('#alarm').val();
var newtime = time+':00';

var dateTime = new Date(date + ' ' + time);
var now = new Date;

var today = new Date();
var datetimediff = dateTime;
var diffMs = (datetimediff - today);
var diffDays = Math.round(diffMs / 86400000); // days
var diffHrs = Math.round((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes

if(diffDays > 0) {
    $('#timeuntil').html('In ' + diffDays + ' days');
} else if(diffHrs > 0) {
    $('#timeuntil').html('In ' + diffHrs + ' hours');
} else if(diffMins > 0) {
    $('#timeuntil').html('In ' + diffMins + ' mins');
} else {
    $('#timeuntil').html('Date is in the past');
}
});
```

From the code above, on change of the datedropper works fine, so I cant see where I'm going wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TimeDropper's default time format is 'h:mm a' which shows the time in 12 hours format... you need to change the format to 'HH:mm'.

and you figured out the newtime variable but forgot to use it:

```
var dateTime = new Date(date + ' ' + newtime);
```